# How to add unique id to file name in cron job?

Tags: cron, filenames

My cronjob looks like this:

```
5 3 * * * mysqldump -u root test > /srv/backup/mysql_daily.dump
```

How can I make filename unique for every time when cronjob writes mysql_daily.dump?

Comment: Please take the time to spell the title properly.  It makes searching much easier for everyone.

Comment: You wrote "How to add uniqie id to file nime in cron job".

Comment: Why don't you use automysqlbackup?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For bash, maybe:

```
... > /srv/backup/mysql_daily-$(date -u +\%Y\%m\%dT\%H\%M\%S)Z.${RANDOM}.dump
```

Personally, i generally only put simple commands in my `crontab`. I'd put this in a little script and use the script in the `crontab`. This would have the benefit of not requiring the `%` characters to be escaped (a common crontab pitfall).

*update* made it [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) per @johan comment

cron

Comment: You could modify the syntax just a little and it would be perfect ISO 8601 date format. [YYYY][MM][DD]T[hh][mm][ss]Z, since you use date -u for UTC you could add a Z after the date ;). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Answer (score 4):

The general practice for this is to use a timestamp using `date +%s` to generate something useful to mark the file (I used seconds as an example but you can use any date format). It's really not necessary to have a truly unique file name as long as the file name doesn't conflict.

```
5 3 * * * mysqldump -u root test > /srv/backup/mysql_daily_`date +\%s`.dump
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
5 3 * * * mysqldump -u root test > /srv/backup/mysql_daily.$(/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d).dump
```

which will put the current [date](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) in the format YYYYMMDD into the filename.